# Being notified when Python security updates are made

Tags: security, python

I maintain a few Python-based web apps. I need to be notified immediately when new Python releases are made, especially micro level releases that fix security issues, so I could update my sites to use the new version.

Is there any way to be automatically notified? I looked at python-announce-list but it has notifications for a myriad of open-source projects that I'm not interested in.

Comment: You mean like their [RSS feed](http://www.python.org/channews.rdf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Michael Hampton pointed out](https://serverfault.com/questions/566334/being-notified-when-python-security-updates-are-made#comment658911_566334), the Python folks maintain [an RSS feed of their updates and changes to the core interpreter/language](http://www.python.org/channews.rdf).

This is more than just security fixes, but if you stay on top of all the Python changes (which aren't that high-volume, judging by the feed) you'll know about any security updates as they happen.

Comment: That link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the news section](https://www.python.org/blogs/) of the Python website, which mostly talks about latest Python releases. It has [an RSS feed](http://feeds.feedburner.com/PythonInsider). You could also follow [@pythoninsider](https://twitter.com/pythoninsider) on Twitter.